# ORM for google App Engine (java)

Tags: java, hibernate, google-app-engine, orm

I developed google endpoints API's & access cloud sql database by using JDBC.now I want to use ORM tool for accessing cloud sql database.
so which ORM tools are supported by google app engine rather that JDO & JPA?
I mean,does hibernate support GAE?

Comment: can you integrate hibernate in GAE.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Hibernate works with GAE Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools).

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158746/hibernate-configuration-for-app-engine

Comment: It's wrong. We are using Hibernate on GAE with Cloud SQL.

Comment: but how to configure hibernate.cfg.xml for accessing cloud sql as well as local mysql instance?

Comment: No need for hibernate.cfg.xml. Configure different `EntityManagerFactory` in code depending on environment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/HibernateJpaServlet.java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google App Engine supports Hibernate ORM in combination with Google Cloud SQL.
We're using this combination in almost all of our Google App Engine projects, sometimes even with connection pooling;

[Can i use HikariCP on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397337/can-i-use-hikaricp-on-google-app-engine)

Cloud SQL can even be used during development;

[Using Google Cloud SQL during Java appengine development (instead of local MySQL instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869422/using-google-cloud-sql-during-java-appengine-development-instead-of-local-mysql)

For the Hibernate connection we've implemented our own ConnectionProvider (i got this idea from [appengine-java-connection-pool](https://github.com/kennberg/appengine-java-connection-pool)). In persistence.xml

[image]

With BasicConnectionProvider;

```
public class BasicConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider, Configurable, Stoppable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5535849343546193022L;
    private static final org.jboss.logging.Logger LOGGER = org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(com.project.server.hibernate.BasicConnectionProvider.class);
    private DriverManagerDataSource mDriverManagerDataSource = null;

    private int mConnectionCount;

    // *************************************************************************
    // Configurable
    // *************************************************************************

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public void configure(Map pProperties) throws HibernateException
    {
        try
        {
            LOGGER.debug("Configuring DataSource");

            DriverManagerDataSource lDriverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

            if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production)
            {
                lDriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
                lDriverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:google:mysql://appengine-id:europe-west1:project/project");
            }
            else
            {
                lDriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                lDriverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project");
            }

            lDriverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
            lDriverManagerDataSource.setPassword("password");

            Properties lProperties = loadConfiguration(pProperties);

            lProperties.put("useSSL", "false");
            lProperties.put("cachePrepStmts", "true");
            lProperties.put("useServerPrepStmts", "true");
            lProperties.put("prepStmtCacheSize", "500");
            lProperties.put("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

            lDriverManagerDataSource.setConnectionProperties(lProperties);

            setDriverManagerDataSource(lDriverManagerDataSource);

            mConnectionCount = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }

        LOGGER.debug("DataSource Configured");
    }

    public static Properties loadConfiguration(Map props)
    {
        Properties lProperties = new Properties();

        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.ISOLATION, props, "transactionIsolation", lProperties);
        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.AUTOCOMMIT, props, "autoCommit", lProperties);
        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, props, "driverClassName", lProperties);
        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.URL, props, "jdbcUrl", lProperties);
        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.USER, props, "username", lProperties);
        copyProperty(AvailableSettings.PASS, props, "password", lProperties);

        return lProperties;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static void copyProperty(String srcKey, Map src, String dstKey, Properties dst)
    {
        if (src.containsKey(srcKey))
        {
            dst.setProperty(dstKey, (String) src.get(srcKey));
        }
    }

    // *************************************************************************
    // ConnectionProvider
    // *************************************************************************

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        Connection lConnection = null;

        if (mDriverManagerDataSource != null)
        {
            lConnection = mDriverManagerDataSource.getConnection();
        }

        mConnectionCount++;
        return lConnection;
    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection(Connection pConnection) throws SQLException
    {
        mConnectionCount--;
        pConnection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType)
    {
        return ConnectionProvider.class.equals(unwrapType)
                || com.project.server.hibernate.BasicConnectionProvider.class.isAssignableFrom(unwrapType)
                || DataSource.class.isAssignableFrom(unwrapType);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType)
    {
        if (ConnectionProvider.class.equals(unwrapType) ||
                com.project.server.hibernate.BasicConnectionProvider.class.isAssignableFrom(unwrapType))
        {
            return (T) this;
        }
        else if (DataSource.class.isAssignableFrom(unwrapType))
        {
            return (T) mDriverManagerDataSource;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnknownUnwrapTypeException(unwrapType);
        }
    }

    // *************************************************************************
    // Stoppable
    // *************************************************************************

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {

    }

    public DriverManagerDataSource getDriverManagerDataSource()
    {
        return mDriverManagerDataSource;
    }

    public void setDriverManagerDataSource(DriverManagerDataSource pDriverManagerDataSource)
    {
        mDriverManagerDataSource = pDriverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```